# InputStream closed error while trying to read response from retrofit.client.Response in 1.9.0

Tags: java, android, retrofit

In retrofit success callback I'm using `response.getBody().in()` to get stream and using following code to convert it to String.

```
        ByteArrayOutputStream result = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            result.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        return result.toString("UTF-8");
```

I get IOException (closed) at in.read(buffer). The above code works fine when retrofit logging is set to RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL, but crashes when set to RestAdapter.LogLevel.NONE.

To debug this further I tried printing the response length via `response.getBody().length()`. I get -1 for RestAdapter.LogLevel.NONE and actual length (2000+) if RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL.

Note : I dont want to use retrofit's model parsing as I want to construct my own model.

I am using retrofit 1.9.0

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have direct experience with Retrofit 1.x. But, in general with Retrofit, fetching the body or errorBody out of the response will return the contents of the body in question and close the connection.

This is why you can't, for example, peek at the body and log it prior to actually trying to use it. Even with successful response this will cause an IOException when you next try to access the body data.

I have no good reason why the logging level at the REST level would be involved here. We'd probably have to see a bit more code to figure that out. I do my logging via the HTTP client (which is the way it works in Retrofit 2). However, that return of -1 indicates that the connection has been closed and all streams associated with it have also been closed.

(We do know that one of the things that changed from Retrofit 1.x is that they removed REST level logging. Apparently, it was always a bit dodgy and didn't necessarily reflect the actual state of the response.)

Retrofit 2 (at least) has a `@Streaming` annotation you apply on the interface method declaration that you can use to fetch the raw octets without deserializing to an object.

If you absolutely need to stay with Retrofit 1.x and can't sort out the REST level logging I'm pretty sure you can chain an HTTP logger interceptor to the OkHTTP client and have Retrofit use that via `setClient()`.